# Fastreport ImageBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, delphi, fastreport

Firstly, I would to portray our system. Our system consists of a combination of C#, ABP framework, and some external tools. We've been using FastReports Open source for our .net core applications. I wanted to add an image to the pdf file we created, but I faced some problems. We added pictures. Although deploy a picture file together with my report, it's not working. The picture area was empty when I wanted to test. By the way, this worked in my local environment. You can find my code here:

```
var pc = virtualFileProvider.GetFileInfo("DesignFiles/ekol-logo.png");
PictureObject pic = report.FindObject("Picture1") as PictureObject;
pic.Image = new Bitmap(pc.CreateReadStream());
```

Comment: Don't post your code as a picture. Use the "Insert code" functionality (the `{}` button).

Comment: If you post code pictures instead of code _text_ you have to expect pictures as answers instead of text which can be selected and copied.